# Async CTP call a wcf ria service method that returns a string value

Tags: silverlight, wcf, service, ria, async-ctp

I'm trying to implement the following into my silverlight wcf ria services project.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/02/using-the-visual-studio-async-ctp-with-ria-services.aspx

It is working fine for entities. However I'm trying to write a custom method that returns a string and throws an error.

Custom method

```
    public string GetHello(string str)
    {
        return ("Hello " + str);
    }
```

Calling from Client

```
String str;

str = await context.LoadAsync(context.GetHello("Sam")).ToString();
```

Error:

> The 'await' operator requires that its operand
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation'
>   have a suitable public GetAwaiter method

Comment: Please double-check your example code. Are you absolutely sure that this client code will result in that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `AsTask` to convert the `InvokeOperation` to a `Task`.

Comment: I tried that and now I get

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation<string>' to 'string'

hstring = await this.parentWindow.ctx.HashString("asdasd").AsTask();

This method works fine if I call it asynchronously(using a delegate). But I'm using async CTP and Kyle's code to call the method synchronously.

Comment: After you `await` it, then read the `InvokeOperation<string>.Value` member. e.g., `(await this.parentWindow.ctx.HashString("asdasd").AsTask()).Value`

Comment: I couldn't find AskTask(). Where is it defined?

Comment: It's in the [blog post you referenced in your question](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/02/using-the-visual-studio-async-ctp-with-ria-services.aspx).